# How make a Sprite's proxy?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, proxy-classes

i'm, following this tutorial
http://www.flashandmath.com/intermediate/swfload/
to load an original swf inside a new one.
What i want to do is a wrapper.
Since some functions was called from external side(scaleform/daapi) to original SWF, i need a way to intercept these function calls to the wrapper and redirect them to original SWF.

I already tried to override callProperty in a Sprite, but it's not possible.

I also tried to extend Proxy class and store inside it a Sprite instance but when i start the application it close immediately.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Comment: ExternalInterface is included in the original SWF, but i don't understand how could be usefull in a wrapper